# How to select correct neural network topology and have 1D array as input (time series prediction)

Tags: neural-network, time-series, prediction

My target is to use RNN in order to predict time series value.

I have 2 problems.

**The first one** is that in my analysis I need 4 different functions to evaluate, let's say A(t), B(t), C(t) and D(t). What I want is to train my NN using 30 samples for each of my functions so I need to input in my node, 4 values [a(1), b(1), c(1), d(1)] and so on...

How can I use 1D array as input?

**My second problem**, is how to select correct topology.

I want to use 30 samples to predict the following ten, so in my NN I have 30 neurons as input layer, and 10 neurons as output layer, but how many hidden layers do I need?

And how many neurons per layer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: And in your opinion I would build a neural network "by hand" or programming it? @EdCottrell your comment is off-topic.

Comment: No need to be rude. Overly-broad questions will be closed. This one is; it doesn't refer to any language, library, or programming topic other than neural networks in general. Another reason to close is: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Verba Docent, Exempla Trahunt

---

### Solution of Problem #1

While no one may constrain you from constructing a super-NN to train, cross-validate & forward-test/evaluate all of **`A`**, **`B`**, **`C`** & **`D`** at once / in parallel.

While NN-s are forgiving in terms of (in)dependence of A,B,C,D ( as opposed to some other AI/ML learners ) such approach to train the super-NN for predicting the whole set of (in)dependent outputs is very inefficient in terms of resources consumption, being O(2+) scaled.

You had much better process performance if you construct **four different NN**-s and train/cross-validate/forward-test each of them for one particular task -> finally having NN(A), NN(B), NN(C) and NN(D) predictors separately, also with a possibility that your NN-s may have different architecture ( [in-hidden.1-hidden.2-...-out]-layers/nodes ).

---

### Solution of Problem #2

There are principally no "pre-baked" (dogmatic) truths available for free on this field.

One may **adopt a test-driven approach** to move across this territory ( marked perhaps as in anxient maps with a warning "Hic Sunt Leones" for area, where the researches were rather afraid ( or lazy ) to go, than reflecting that there were indeed observed any ( claimed ) lions overthere ).

Once you **define a goal & metrics** for evaluation of `{ poor | better | good-enough | best }` performance of a NN-under-test, no one ( but time & budget ) may restrict you from creating as many architectures as you can imagine.

**The results matter**. So overfitting and bias will be your main enemies and some architectures will demonstrate it's capability to handle these better, some worse.

Supposing the scale ( TFLOPs / PFLOPs ) of your problem allows to empower your AI/ML-engine with some additional synthetic features ( derived from learning examples ), the feature-engineering may help your AI/ML-learners perform better much more, than the (extensive) modifications of the NN-architecture.

---

### Nota Bene on RNNs

Should your remark on a plan to use a **R**NN shall have a meaning of so called **Recurrent Neural Networks**, your further AI/ML-research shall go into details of architecture/topology of these, special cases, rather than "mechanically" using the plain, forward feeding, error back propagating NN-based learners.

> Do not hesitate to ask more, Francesco & enjoy joining this great StackOverflow Community

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to follow your indication and I'll let you know evolution of my project!